# txt data delimited with multiple | extraction data with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file of data with `|` as delimiter like this with multiple same delimited rows. Here is example of 3 rows:

```
LOW|||IregularFeature|ENS0111548|promotor||||||||||rs4564187963|
HIGH|||IregularityFeature|ENS0dse58|exon||||||||||rs456456187992|
MODIFIER|||Iregular|ENS0111548|promotor||||||||||rs4564187963|
```

I wanted the data extract all data with `awk` into columns tab separated format (every space between fields below is a tab character):

```
LOW     IregularFeature ENS0111548      promotor        rs4564187963
HIGH    IregularityFeature      ENS0dse58       exon    rs456456187992
MODIFIER        Iregular        ENS0111548      promotor        rs4564187963
```

I tried to set delimiter in output to tab and with if conditional and for loop pick up the data:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|",OFS="\t"}; for(i = $1; i <= $NF; i ++);if(i!= ""){print i}'
```

Comment: `i` is a number from 1 to the number of fields. You might need to print (and check) `$i` ?  (`if($i!= ""){print $i}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
|Hi|||name||||
|Ha|||SA||||
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^|]+";OFS="\t"}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
Hi  name
Ha  SA
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is one or more (`+`) characters which are not (`^`) pipe (`|`) and output field separator is tab. For every line do `$1=$1` (in order to trigger string rebuild) and `print` such line

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F'[|]+' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/\|$/,""); $1=$1}1' file
LOW     IregularFeature ENS0111548      promotor        rs4564187963
HIGH    IregularityFeature      ENS0dse58       exon    rs456456187992
MODIFIER        Iregular        ENS0111548      promotor        rs4564187963
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases where that doesn't work.